# How to multi-word search

Tags: search, find-file

When I use `swiper` to search inside a buffer I can use multiple search words separated by a blank space. This works.

But I also want that behaviour when search for a file (`C-x f`), a variable or function (`C-h f` or `C-h v`) or via `M-x` (what is this?) or finding a `org-roam` node.

I have `cousel` and `ivy` here and not sure which one of that packages is relevant for a the needed feature.

Comment: Enable `ivy-mode` and `counsel-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can:

1. Match any number of search patterns (e.g. words, literal strings, regexps) during completion.  So you can use that to match file names with `C-x C-f`, function names with `C-h f`, etc.
2. Match not only file names this way (i.e., with multiple search patterns) but also, or instead, file contents. In Icicle minor mode `C-x C-f` is bound to the multi-completion command `icicle-file`, which lets you match either file name or file contents, or both, any number of times (e.g. with different patterns).  `C-h f icicle-file` tells you this:

> **`C-x C-f`** runs the command **`icicle-file`** (found in `icicle-mode-map`), which
> is an interactive compiled Lisp function in [`icicles-cmd1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-cmd1.el).
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar file icicles icicle-file`, `open`, `C-x C-f`,
> `menu-bar file new-file`.
>
> `(icicle-file ARG)`
>
> Visit a file or directory.
>
> - With *no* prefix argument, use relative file names (`icicle-find-file`).
> - With a prefix argument, use absolute file names (`icicle-find-file-absolute`).
> - With a *negative* prefix arg, you can choose also by **date**:
>   Completion candidates include the last modification date.
>
> All of these commands let you **search file content**, as well as file
> **names** (unless you use an Emacs version prior to 23).  See
> `icicle-find-file` and `icicle-find-file-absolute` for more
> information.
>
> Note that when you use a prefix arg, completion matches candidates as
> ordinary strings.  It knows nothing of file names per se.  In
> particular, you cannot use remote file-name syntax if you use a prefix
> argument.
>
> If you use a prefix arg when you act on a completion candidate, then
> you visit the file or dir in *read-only* mode.  This includes when you
> act on all candidates using **`C-!`**: precede the `C-!` with a prefix
> arg.  This does not apply to the final candidate chosen (using `RET`
> or `mouse-2`) - a prefix arg has no effect for that.
>
> During completion (***** means this requires library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus)), you
> can use the following keys:
>
> - `C-c C-d`      - change the `default-directory' (with a prefix arg)
> - `C-c +`        - create a new directory
> - `C-backspace`  - go up one directory level
> - `M-|`          - open Dired on the currently matching file names
> - `S-delete`     - delete candidate file or (empty) dir
> - ***** `C-x C-t *`    - narrow to files with all of the tags you specify
> - ***** `C-x C-t +`    - narrow to files with some of the tags you specify
> - ***** `C-x C-t % *`  - narrow to files with all tags matching a regexp
> - ***** `C-x C-t % +`  - narrow to files with some tags  matching a regexp
> - ***** `C-x a +`      - add tags to current candidate
> - ***** `C-x a -`      - remove tags from current candidate
> - ***** `C-x m`        - access file bookmarks (not just autofiles)
>
> By default, Icicle mode remaps all key sequences that are normally bound
> to `find-file` to `icicle-file`.  If you do not want this remapping,
> then customize option `icicle-top-level-key-bindings`.

For more info about `icicle-file` and other file-accessing commands see [Icicles - File-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input).